# Rails API get params to a custom method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

Am trying to filter some data from database but its not getting params. This is my method:

```
def user_orders
 orders = Order.select { | item | item[:user_id] == params[:id] }
 if orders
  render json: orders, status: :ok
 else
  render json: {error: "No orders available"}
 end
end
```

This is the custom routing

`get "/orders/user/:id", to: "orders#user_orders"`

and the response is an empty array. However if I pass in a number in the method like so:

`orders = Order.select { | item | item[:user_id] == 27 }`

I get back the filtered array as expected. How can I pass in a dynamic ID from the routing?

Comment: What does the line in the rails log say? It should start with GET /user/orders and it should list what parameters have actually been received.

Comment: This is what am  getting: 

Parameters: {"user_id"=>1, "snack_id"=>6, "quantity"=>6, "id"=>"27", "order"=>{"quantity"=>6, "user_id"=>1, "snack_id"=>6}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: if your parameters look like this:

Parameters: `{ … "order"=>{…"user_id"=>27}}`

… then you need to access the user_id as `params[:order][:user_id]`.

Otherwise your conditional is comparing `nil` to `27`, which will return false, and so nothing is ever selected.

If you’re querying an activerecord model, I also recommend that you use `Order.where(item: {user_id: params[:id]})` to find your list of orders, so that and rails can cast to the right type as well.

What does the line in the rails log say? It should start with `GET /user/orders` and it should list what parameters have actually been received. Alternatively you can use puts to check the content of params.

Comment: I don't think that the issue is a conditional render because if I pass in a value of a user ID instead I get a filtered array back